# I am not able to upload my localhost website on live server. It is not showing the background images

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have uploaded my website many times with the help of plugins and direct also.

But this is always showing error with the background images.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope you must have changed images path using sql query.

Comment: Hi @hariom Singh, what error you are getting when you upload this site on server.
Please share your site link.

Comment: please post code..how you are setting path for background images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9945519/nir. @nir sir when I change "wp_option" path with live domain in SQL. some pages opening really good but some pages are sitll opening in localhost & stll problem with the background images. When I change the path of entire SQL with live domain it does only show header not even dropdowns & content are totally disappear. What to do please revert. Thanks a lot for your attention. Hello Yogesh sir, I am getting these error as I mentioned above. this is the website link ( http://www.matrixparel.com/ ). Please revert I need your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2935004/charan-kumar. Hello chandan sir I am setting the path as I mentioned above please revert.

Comment: I guess you might have put static path in editor or some where that is why it shows error of image not found in your console. Following these exact steps might help you. https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Comment: Yes maybe but this is only happening with the background images except all the images are working fine. So please tell me how can I fix it now?. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I inspected your code and there are some images path that you need to change in your css file. Please look into that. It also shows some old css from cache plugin. Kindly please flush you cache or disable cache plugin for some time.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/users/9945519/nir. Hello @nir sir. I have used a plugin called beaver builder. But I don't know how can I change its URL. Would you help, please? How can I flush you cache or disable cache plugin.

Comment: To flush your web page press Ctrl + F5 or Ctrl + R . Just go to plugin section to see whether there is any cache plugin or not, if there is than deactivate it temporary. Alternatively you can try changing permalink of webpages. Go to Dashboard > settings > permalink  select custom post .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9945519/nir @nir appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

There are several things that you need to check regarding the name and path of the image:
make sure you are using correct name , if you are doing development on Windows , then windows is case insensitive , if your image file name has capital letters then you must right your image name in code in capital letter , also check for extension, if it is also in capital then write it in code as capitals. Or rename your image file according to the name you right in code. Cause server uses linux is and Linus file names are case sensitive . If do not solve you issue then give me the link to live site I'll check it.

Comment: OP hasn't even added code to question - don't answer - it's a quick way to downvotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7611062/thisguyhastwothumbs Hello sir you need t read all the brief properly by the way. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @HariomSingh to mention a user use @ followed by the username :) | however, we still need to see your code, a brief bit of text won't show us what's wrong